# Twilio Python Whatsapp api

Tags: python-3.x, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

Please help me with this problem, I want to get input from the customer using Twilio, the input can be any Item and each item have some price, such as;

Hoodies1: $99

Hoodies2: $98

Hoodies3: $96

Hoodies4: $95 ..... and so on. Note: The price of each item can be different.

**Code:**

```
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse
from flask import Flask, request, session

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/sms', methods=['POST'])
def bot():
    incoming_msg = request.form['Body']
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    msg = resp.message()

    List2=[]
    List1=[None,99,98,97,96,95,94,93,92]
    List = [None,"Hoodies1","Hoodies2","Hoodies3","Hoodies4","Hoodies5","Hoodies6","Hoodies7","Hoodies8"]
    for i in range(0, 9):
        if List[i] == incoming_msg:
            List2.append(List1[i])
            msg.body(f'Price: {List1[i]}')
            print(f"Input from Whatsapp is Hoodies{i}\t List2:",List2)
    return str(resp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

With each incoming_msg the whole code runs again, this is the problem, if I give input from WhatsApp "Hoodies1" so the code will append the price of "Hoodies1" which is $99 to list 2, and if I again give another Input "Hoodies2" (price is $98) it will be replaced with the previous value of $99. Can anybody help me with this problem?

[image]

Comment: I want to append price according to the input given from WhatsApp to list 2, for example. if I entered Hoodies1 List2 should be [99] then if I entered Hoodies2 List2 should be [99,98] then if I entered Hoodies5 List2 should be [99,98,95] and so on. In my code with each input given from customer via WhatsApp each time replaces with previous value with newer value.

Comment: List  and List1 are hardcoded, suppose if another time you change the values inside both lists which you will eventually do in the future, you will not need these values again. The point I'm trying to raise is that your code should at least handle the List1 and List  items  dynamically.

Comment: I can make it general, will not be hardcoded anymore. but here the issue is not hardcode, the issue is every time with each incoming_msg from WhatsApp it runs from starting. can you append the prices of the item to list2 which we get input from WhatsApp?